# Publishing fails with java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Tags: 2013-sp1, publishing, transport

Publishing is failing and I can see following errors in the log file.

> 2017-01-04 18:26:16,011 ERROR TransportService - Unexpected error
>   occurred. java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
>
> 2017-01-04 18:59:55,918 ERROR DestinationController - Unknown error
>   occurred, continuing to guarantee transport does not stop
>   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

What should I do to fix it ?

Comment: Are you seeing any deployer errors? You are obviously running out of heap space. Can you also update your questions with relevant use cases similar to http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/12678/deploying-failure-during-publish